# UTF-8 JSON file is encoded with wrong characters

Tags: json, angularjs, utf-8, encode, translate

In my angularjs application I use pascal precht translate. To load the desired language I use the $translatePartialLoader provider. This works ok for languages with just ascii characters. I've structured my json files with an URL template like:  urlTemplate: '/app/i18n/{part}/{lang}.json'

Loading is not the problem, encoding is wrong.[image: the file as loaded in the browser]

The original JSON file: [image: original file]

What can I do?

The web.config looks like:

```
<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
<customHeaders>
   <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, postcheck=0, max-age=0, s-maxage=0"/>
   <add name="Pragma" value="no-cache"/>
   <add name="Expires" value="0"/>
</customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
</modules>
<staticContent>
   <mimeMap fileExtension="woff" mimeType="application/font-woff"/>
   <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="7.00:00:00"/>
   <mimeMap fileExtension="woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff"/>
   <remove fileExtension=".pdf" />
   <mimeMap fileExtension=".pdf" mimeType="application/pdf"  />
   <remove fileExtension=".txt" />
   <mimeMap fileExtension=".txt" mimeType="text/plain; charset=utf-8" />
   <remove fileExtension=".json" />
   <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json; charset=utf-8" />
</staticContent>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering allowHighBitCharacters="true" allowDoubleEscaping="true">
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="157286400" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: _What can I do?_ [UTF-8 Everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/). There is no chance for [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) in a rigorous  _UTF-8_ environment…

Comment: I do not understand your comment.